# Error al enviar email con datos traídos de campos de texto

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas. Mi problema es el siguiente. Estoy terminando una tienda online la cual posee un carrito de compras común y corriente, el usuario tendra dos opciones al haber verificado su carrito de compras:

1-Realizar el pedido de la mercancia
2-Pagar a través de la pasarela de pago

Al realizar el pedido de la mercancía el usuario debe llenar un formulario con sus datos, este formulario tiene unos input los cuales tienen el resumen de la compra, que si los productos, precio, cantidad, subtotal y total. Este resumen de la compra quiero que le llegue al correo al usuario cuando haga el pedido.

El problema esta en que al enviar el email cuando reviso la bandeja solo manda el ultimo producto del carrito de compras, no guarda todo el pedido. Y necesito que el usuario vea en su bandeja de entrada el resumen de la compra. Mi código es el siguiente:

Mi formulario:

```
<form action="contact_me.php" method="POST">
<?php 
    for($i=0;$i<count($datos);$i++){   
    ?>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="productos" value="<?php echo $datos[$i]['Nombre'];?>">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="price" value="<?php echo $datos[$i]['Precio'];?>">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="canti" value="<?php echo $datos[$i]['Cantidad'];?>">
    <input class="form-control" name="sub_total" value="<?php echo $datos[$i]['Cantidad']*$datos[$i]['Precio'];?>">
    <?php } ?>
    <input class="form-control" name="total_pagar" value="<?php echo $total?>">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Nombres</label>
        <input name="nombre" type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Número de Telefono</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Tu correo electronico</label>
        <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placerholder="">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="Enviar">
  </div>
  </form>
```

Mi archivo de envio de correo:

```
 <?php 

 $oMail = new PHPMailer();

 $oMail->isSMTP();
 $oMail->Host = 'smtp.mailtrap.io';
 $oMail->Username = 'd0d3fbbf3877b5';
 $oMail->Password = '020d21ae1f0055';

 $oMail->SMTPAuth = true;
 $oMail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
 $oMail->Port = 2525;
 $oMail->CharSet = "UTF-8";

 $name = $_POST['nombre'];
 $oMail->From = $_POST['email'];
 $oMail->addAddress('gpojava@gmail.com');

 $oMail->Subject = 'HOLA: ' . $name . " " . 'HAS REALIZADO UN PEDIDO A MV 
 MULTISERVICIOS' ;
 $oMail->Body = $_POST['productos'] . $_POST['price'] . $_POST['canti'] . 
 '<br>' . 
 $_POST['sub_total'] . $_POST['total_pagar'];

if($oMail->send() == false){
echo $oMail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
 echo "Bien";
}
```

Como ya mencione el resultado que tengo de eso es que solo envia el ultimo producto que genera el for. Y quiero enviar todos los productos como resumen de compra.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que hay varios input con el mismo nombre, entonces por defecto siempre toma el último input, lo que se podría hacer es guardar un arreglo en una varible de sesión y en el archivo que envía el email, accede a ese arreglo que dejó en la varible de sesión, lo recorre con un for y lo concatena

Comment: Ok jonathan. Sabes que tengo ese arreglo que es el del carrito de compras asi, $_SESSION['carrito'] = $arreglo; ese arreglo me contiene los datos del carrito. Me dices que en el archivo de envio de email acceda a el con esto mismo $datos = $_SESSION['carrito']; y con un for haga esto for($i=0; $i<count($datos){ aqui dento que es lo que tendria que ir}

Comment: Ahí es donde arma el `$oMail->Body =` , lo que hace en el for es ir concatenando cada "registro" de su carrito de compras en una variable cualquiera Ej:
$cuerpo="";
 for($i=0; $i<count($datos){ 
 $cuerpo+=$_POST['productos'] . $_POST['price'] . $_POST['canti'] . '<br>' ;
}
$oMail->Body =$cuerpo;

Comment: Ok, probare de esa manera. Y por ejemplo si quisiera enviar esos datos dentro de contenido HTML? Como se lo agregaria? dentro del for a cada $_POST?

Comment: Lo concatena según la estructura que quiera, así como concatenó el <br>. 
Otra cosa que podría hacer es crea una función en una clase la cual usted le enviara los parametros de precio y demás, y que esta le generara la estructura html que usted desee.
Me parece más escalable que sea así.

Comment: Jhonatan he hecho lo que me dijiste pero modificando algunas cosas y el resultado es el mismo, solo me envia el ultimo articulo del carrito de compras

Answer (score 0):

Lo más fácil sería en vez de enviar un input que sea un valor simple, que ese input sea un array, tal que así:

```
<?php 
  for($i=0;$i<count($datos);$i++){   
?>
     <input class="form-control" type="text" name="productos[$i][]" value="<?php echo $datos[$i]['Nombre'];?>">
     <input class="form-control" type="text" name="price[$i][]" value="<?php echo $datos[$i]['Precio'];?>">
     <input class="form-control" type="text" name="canti[$i][]" value="<?php echo $datos[$i]['Cantidad'];?>">
     <input class="form-control" name="sub_total[$i][]" value="<?php echo $datos[$i]['Cantidad']*$datos[$i]['Precio'];?>">
<?php
   } 
?>
```

Luego en contact_me.php recorres estos array y listo. La opción de meter en session el carrito sería lo mejor, por si el usuario cierra la ventana sin querer.

Comment: Saludos monchy. Entiendo. La forma en que pueda recorrer esos array sera algo asi?                                                            if($_POST)
 {
 foreach ($_POST as $clave=>$valor)
     {
     echo "El valor de $clave es: $valor";
     }
 }

Comment: algo así:
   `if($_POST) {
         foreach($_POST['productos'] as $key => $value) {
               echo 'El producto '. $value.' tiene un precio '.$_POST['price'][$key].' y quiere .'$_POST['canti'][$key];
         }
     }`